# Pure JavaScript "custom function" equivalent of $ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to use jQuery and I want to create a function that is similar to $ in jQuery.

Using code that is not a function is not suitable for what I want.

For example, we can use a code like this in jQuery:

```
$('.myClass').specialFunction();
```

Its equivalent in pure JavaScript is something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass').forEach(el=>{el.specialFunction()});
```

But this increases the size of the code. I am looking for a function that can execute something like this:

```
myfunc('.myClass').specialFunction();
```

If there is one element in myClass I can do this:

```
var myFunc=function(slct){
    return document.querySelector(slct)
}
```

but if there are multiple elements in this class, what must we do?

It is not possible that return multiple elements from myFunc function.

and if using `return document.querySelectorAll(slct)` i can't call some JavaScript function such as `addEventListener` on returned object.

How to create such a myfunc function?

Comment: This is very open-ended, you're basically asking how to create a replacement library. You might want to [read this](https://dev.to/rfornal/-replacing-jquery-with-vanilla-javascript-1k2g) or ask a more specific question.

Comment: No dear friend.  I need 10 or 12 jquery functions, all of which I have created.  In this case, I asked a library for only one function

Comment: What do you want `myfunc('.myClass')` to return exactly? It sounds like you want to be able to use `addEventListener` on it while also using other custom methods on it? Note that jQuery doesn't allow you to use `.addEventListener()` on `$(".myClass")`, it provides it's own methods like `.on` or `.click()` which implicitly loop through everything matched by the selector.

Comment: Yes, I want to use several functions including `addEventListener` on it.  True, jquery does not allow this, but in jquery you can use events on the returned object from the $ function.  I want to be able to do the same

Comment: It sounds like a class that internally tracks the matches, applies whatever function you call, and then always ends with `return this`.

Comment: For example, suppose the selected element is an input tag and I want to determine with the keyup event whether the text in the input should be rtl or ltr.  So I should be able to call `addEventListener(keyup, detectDir())` on the returned object.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might end up creating a new Library, but in short :

```
function $query(selector) {
  if (typeof selector === 'object' && selector !== null) {
    return selector;
  } else {
    let choice = selector[0]; // # or . etc
    if (!['*', '.', '#'].includes(choice)) {
      choice = '';
    }
    let selectorName = selector.toString().replace(choice, '');
    switch (choice) {
      case '#':
        return document.getElementById(selectorName);

      case '.':
        return document.getElementsByClassName(selectorName);
      case '*':
        return document.getElementsByName(selectorName);
      case '':
        return document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
      default:
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }
  }
}

// ### USAGE 
let appDiv = $query('#app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>using ID</h1>`;

// TAG NAME
appDiv = $query('p');
appDiv[0].innerHTML = `<h1>using TagName</h1>`;

// CLASS NAME
appDiv = $query('.app');
appDiv[0].innerHTML = `<h1>using ClassName</h1>`;

// BY NAME
appDiv = $query('*app');
appDiv[0].innerHTML = `<h1>using Name</h1>`;
```

[Try here at Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7hktev?file=index.js,index.html)

You can add more features to it, depending on the need.
You can use prototype

You can also use this Build in Simple function:

```
document.querySelector(YOUR_Query);
```

Comment: I haven't tested your answer yet, but it looks like you're right, thanks